# How would you make this not so common Android UI pattern?

Tags: android, ui-patterns

I have used an Android application recently that has an interesting UI pattern in it. I have made two screenshots to show you what I'm talking about:

**Initial State (look at the blue rectangle on the right of the screen):**

[image]

**After clicking on that blue rectangle, it slides smoothly to the left, which results in the following screen:**

[image]

My question is simple, how do you think this could be achieved? Also, what's the name of this pattern? A sliding pane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called sliding drawer in the android vocabulary.
You can find is as an ui component.
To obtain the same result you would actually need to change the default handle to a blue one (from an image a priori).

Some links on the topic:

- [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)
- [A good example on how to customize it](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/)

Comment: Ah! I was 100% wrong, it's pure Android -- indeed the menu on Android itself is a sliding drawer! Thanks for this answer, helps a lot!